# k-means in R, usage of nstart parameter?

Tags: r, k-means

I try to use k-means clusters (using SQLserver + R), and it seems that my model is not stable : each time I run the **k-means** algorithm, it finds different clusters. But if I set **nstart** (in R k-means function) high enough (10 or more) it becomes stable.

The default value for this parameter is 1 but it *seems* that setting it to a higher value (25) is recommended (I think I saw somewhere in the documentation).

So I'm a bit confused...
Any advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stability of the clusters is highly dependent on your dataset, for clear cut cases running it multiple times is a waste of resources. I think that is the rationale behind the default value of 1. But I agree that for most smaller cases setting it much higher makes a lot of sense.

Comment: default = 1 just for a matter of performance ? ok, that make sense... thanks

Answer (score 9):

**nstart** option attempts multiple initial configurations and reports on the best one. For example, adding nstart=25 will generate 25 initial random centroids and choose the best one for the algorithm. Hope this helps!

[You can read more here...](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/08/k-means-clustering-from-r-in-action/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, nstart will create multiple configurations and will show the best one.

For example, nstart = 25 , will create 25 initial configurations.

Use nstart argument to try multiple random initial values.

Answer (score -2):

the explanation doesn't appear naywhere in doc. but I think that setting nstart higher let kmeans run nstart(say 50) random initialization of centroids and choose the one that minimize better the cost; therefore you end up with a much more stable clusters becouse of kmeans always choose the better separation for your data